# How to push my Heroku app on my personal Github account?

Tags: heroku, github, repository

I created an application on Heroku. The application is pushed to my git@heroku.com:[My-project-name].git.

I would like to push this application to my own Github account. How can I do it?

By the way, doing:

```
git clone git@heroku.com:[My-project-name].git
```

gives back:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're already signed in to Heroku account. Use the following command instead to clone an existing app to your local machine:

```
heroku git:clone -a your_app_name
cd your_app_name
```

This will clone your app on your current working directory, and then navigate to `your_app_name`. Then you can add your github repo's remote by:

```
git remote add origin url_to_your_github_repo
```

And finally run the following command to push the code to github:

```
git push origin master
```